# Notifications not showing in fullscreen mode Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, google-chrome, notification, telegram

So, I don't receive notifications from the Telegram application when I watching a YouTube video in fullscreen mode. I tried to find something about that in google, but I didn't found anything, only old posts.

I also found "Fullscreen notifications" plugin for GNOME, but it doesn't support from GNOME 44+.

Also, when I exit full screen mode, notifications appear, but I want them to appear even when I'm watching a video.

- There is nothing about this in telegram (no function)
- There is also nothing about this in the Ubuntu settings.

Any ideas (how can I turn it on)?

===

- I'm using: **Ubuntu 22.04 on Wayland**
- Browser: **Chrome**

*P.S. I didn't test it with another apps, also I didn't test urgent notifications like: Battery Low, etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve the problem:**

1. I switched from Wayland to X11 (Xorg)
2. I also installed nvidia drivers

Now I can see notifications even in fullscreen mode.

P.S. I didn’t switched to Wayland before only because of the lack of gestures, if someone is also concerned about this, use this guide to enable touchpad gestures on X11: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/06/touchpad-gestures-ubuntu-22-04-xorg/